# A no seconds added to timer for Android

Tags: java, android

I make a timer with seconds, minutes, hours and use NumberPicker (separate for seconds, minutes and hours). I can set the minutes and hours, but I can’t seconds (when I select any value except 60, my timer does not change, and if 60 everything works). Please tell me how to solve this problem. (Values ​​are set by pressing the button).

```
mButtonSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int resH;
        int resS;

        if (numberPickerHor.getValue() != 0) {
            resH = numberPickerHor.getValue() * 60;
        } else {
            resH = 0;
        }
        if (numberPickersek.getValue() != 0) {
            resS = numberPickersek.getValue() / 60;
        } else {
            resS = 0;
        }

        int res = resH + numberPickerMin.getValue() + resS;
        String ress = String.valueOf(res);
        numberPickerHor.setValue(0);
        numberPickerMin.setValue(0);
        numberPickersek.setValue(0);
        long millisInput = Long.parseLong(ress) * 60000;

        setTime(millisInput);
    }
});
```

Update time and record numbers:

```
private void updateCountDownText() {
    int hours = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 3600;
    int minutes = (int) ((mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 3600) / 60;
    int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;
    String timeLeftFormatted;
    if (hours > 0) {
        timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                "%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
    } else {
        timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
    }
    mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing division result into `int`, so your result is truncated. For example: You select 30, your code will do 30 / 60 = 0.5, you want to store it in `int`, so you will get 0. 
Only 60 will result in 60 / 60 = 1.

Suggestion: work with seconds, not minutes.

```
resH = numberPickerHor.getValue() * 60 * 60; // hour to seconds
resM = numberPickerMin.getValue() * 60;      // minutes to seconds
resS = numberPickersek.getValue();

long millisInput = resH + resM + resS * 1000  //millis for timer
```